# Do we need a tag covering paragliding and similar sports?

Tags: discussion

We have a strange dearth of questions on paragliding, sky diving, and base-jumping, and hence no tag that I could find.

I don't think it makes sense to have a tag for each of these and possible others that I don't know about.  (What's the name for sailing in the air over water behind a motor boat? But that should probably be a subset of water skiing.) I thought of free-falling, but in free-fall one does not encounter air resistance, so that tag wouldn't work for these sports.

**???**

Answer (score 5):

The general rule is to create tags once they are needed, not create tags to then fill.

If we start to get questions on this topic (I think Charlie is right in suggesting they'll probably go to aviation) then we can look at creating tags for them.

Answer (score 4):

The general point has already been made by the other answers: A tag should be created when it is needed. So no "catch-all" tag is necessary. I actually wrote this for another point:

I believe paragliding and other "flying" activities like sky-diving, base-jumping, ... are very much on topic here. Aviation is a very technical site, questions on paragliding are about aerodynamics and airspace regulation. That kind of thing definitely belongs there, but practical questions are better suited here. Also mountaineering as a big topic of TGO has ties to paragliding, in that many mountaineers also do paraglide and some combine the two.

Answer (score 3):

As for right now, I think just [paragliding](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paragliding) works. I don't see the need to create an "umbrella tag" and I think that right now its just fine.

Just because there is only one question to a tag doesn't make the tag bad in and of itself. See [salamanders](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salamanders) for example. Its still worthwhile to create the tags so that other people don't have to and to help our SEO.

As a side note, maybe/perhaps/don't really have a strong opion [paragliding](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paragliding) questions would be better off on Aviation.SE?

Comment: Paragliding has been used by speed alpinists for quicker descents down mountains. Ueli Steck used a light paraglider the summer he climbed all 82 summits in the Alps over 4,000m in only 62 days.

Comment: Charlie, can you please tell me what SEO is? I should probably know what you mean, but I don't! Maybe Search Engine something?

Comment: @Sue search engines optimization

Comment: Thanks.  I was almost there!